# Redux state reverts to previous state after navigation or browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple 'post-like' application built with react and redux. When the user is signed in, he should see one navbar, when he is not, he should see another.

I am using redux-devtools to keep track of the state changes.

The issue is, that when I log in, I set a local storage token and when I log out, I set that token to null. This approach works fine, when I click on logout, I see the token being `null` and `user_authenticated` being false in the redux devtools, however when I go back to the homepage, or click the browser back button, it reverts to the `login` state, I can then see the token value and `is_authenticated` being set to true.

When I refresh the page, I get my desired behavior that is the user logs out, the token is set to null, and `is_authenticated` set to false.

The weird thing is if I do `console.log(store.getState())`, I get the updated/expected state there, but the devtools show the previous state, and the page even behaves like the previous state.

The same is the case with login, going back and forth in navigation gets me the old state that was there when I first visited that page.

State from my redux-devtools, after going back to the homepage, after logging out.

```
user: {
    is_authenticated: true,
    token: 'c80c632a6529b79d51fd3e2fc915cfb94834aa5237b4e65924c095ea58f289b3',
    is_loading: false
  },
```

State from `store.getState()` on the same page, after moving back from logout

```
user:
is_authenticated: false
is_loading: false
token: "null"
```

Some of my components are listed below:

routes.js

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Homepage from './components/homepage';
import Scammer from './components/scammer';
import ScammerCreate from './components/scammer_create'
import Navbar from './components/navbar'
import Register from './components/register'
import Login from './components/login'
import Logout from './components/logout'
import {store} from './index'




class Routes extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'get_user',
        })
        store.getState()
    }
    

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
    
                
                <Navbar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Homepage}/>
                    <Route path="/scammer/create" exact component={ScammerCreate}></Route>
                    <Route path="/scammer/:id" exact component={Scammer}/>
                    <Route path="/auth/register" exact component={Register}></Route>
                    <Route path="/auth/login" exact component={Login}></Route>
                    <Route path="/auth/logout" exact component={Logout}></Route>
                    
                </Switch>
                </div>
            )
        }
}

export default Routes;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import Routes from './routes'

import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

//const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware)(createStore)
const middleware = [promiseMiddleware,thunkMiddleware]
export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}> 
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

user_reducer

```
let initialState = {

}
if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null && localStorage.getItem('token') != 'null'){
    initialState['is_authenticated'] = true;
    initialState['token'] = localStorage.getItem('token');
    initialState['is_loading'] = false;
}

else{
    initialState ={
        'is_authenticated' : false,
        'token' : localStorage.getItem('token'),
        'is_loading' : false,
    }
    
}

export default function user(state=initialState,action){

    if (action.type == "registered") {
        localStorage.setItem('token',action.payload.token);
        return {...state, 'user_details': action.payload.user,'token':localStorage.getItem('token'),'is_authenticated':true,'is_loading':false}

    }

    else if ( action.type == "login" ){
        
        console.log(action.payload)
        localStorage.setItem('token',action.payload.token)
        return {
            ...state,'is_authenticated' : true, 'token' : localStorage.getItem('token'),'is_loading' : false,
            'user_details' : action.payload.user,
        }
    }

    else if( action.type == "logout" ){
        localStorage.setItem("token",null);
        return {
            ...state,'is_authenticated' : false, 'token' : localStorage.getItem('token'), 'is_loading' : false
        }
    }

    else if(action.type == 'get_user'){
       const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       console.log(token)
       if (token != null && token != 'null'){
           return {
               ...state,'is_authenticated' : true, token : token, is_loading : false,
           }

        }
        else {
            return {
                ...state, is_authenticated : false, token: token, is_loading : false,
            }
    
    }
    }

    else{
        return initialState;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after days of debugging, and going through redux tutorials from start to end and still failing.

I finally realized that i was returning initialState for default action. So when ever a new component would load, it would get the initialState rather than updated state.

Comment: My problem was that I was returning ínitial state' as a default action. For me, just removing the default action worked.

Answer (score 0):

Redux reducers should ***always*** return a state value. In your case the issue is default returning the ***initial*** state instead of the ***current*** state.

Update the reducer to align with Redux reducer suggested patterns.

Example:

```js
export default function user(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "registered":
      localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        user_details: action.payload.user,
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        is_authenticated: true,
        is_loading: false
      };

    case "login":
      localStorage.setItem('token',action.payload.token)
      return {
        ...state,
        is_authenticated: true,
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        is_loading: false,
        user_details: action.payload.user,
      };

    case "logout":
      localStorage.setItem("token",null);
      return {
        ...state,
        is_authenticated: false,
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        is_loading: false
      };

    case "get_user":
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      return {
        ...state,
        is_authenticated: token != null && token != 'null',
        token,
        is_loading: false,
      };

    default:
      return state; // <-- no case matched, return current state
  }
}
```